# When can I say that I have a good knowledge on linux

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I heard that linux operating systems are fast and they can be customized to as our needs. i have installed linux mint 17. I would like to learn about linux. What are things that i can learn on linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be it's not very original, but I think list of topics from LFS101x.2 Introduction to Linux [course](https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-linux-linuxfoundationx-lfs101x-2) could help:

1. Chapter 01: The Linux Foundation (not very useful)
2. Chapter 02: Linux Philosophy and Concepts

> Section 1: Linux History
>
> Section 2: Linux Philosophy
>
> Section 3: Linux Community
>
> Section 4: Linux Terminology
>
> Section 5: Linux Distributions

3. Chapter 03: Linux Structure and Installation

> Section 1: Linux Filesystem Basics
>
> Section 2: The Boot Process
>
> Section 3: Linux Distribution Installation

4. Chapter 04: Graphical Interface

> Section 1: Session Management
>
> Section 2: Basic Operations
>
> Section 3: Graphical Desktop

5. Chapter 05: System Configuration from the Graphical Interface

> Section 1: System, Display, Date and Time Settings
>
> Section 2: Network Manager
>
> Section 3: Installing and Updating Software

6. Chapter 06: Finding Linux Documentation

> Section 1: Documentation Sources
>
> Section 2: The man pages
>
> Section 3: GNU Info
>
> Section 4: Help Command
>
> Section 5: Other Documentation Sources

7. Chapter 07: Command Line Operations

> Section 2: Basic Operations
>
> Section 3: Searching for Files
>
> Section 4: Working with Files
>
> Section 5: Installing Software

8. Chapter 08: File Operations

> Section 1: Filesystems
>
> Section 2: Filesystem Architecture
>
> Section 3: Comparing Files and File Types
>
> Section 4: Backing Up and Compressing Data

9. Chapter 09: User Environment

> Section 1: Accounts
>
> Section 2: Environment Variables
>
> Section 3: Recalling Previous Commands
>
> Section 4: Command Aliases
>
> Section 5: File Permissions

10. Chapter 10: Text Editors

> Section 1: Basic Editors: nano and gedit
>
> Section 2: More Advanced Editors: vi and emacs

11. Chapter 11: Local Security Principles

> Section 1: Understanding Linux security
>
> Section 2: Understanding the usage of the root account
>
> Section 3: Using sudo, the Importance of Process Isolation, Limiting
>   Hardware Access and Keeping Systems Current
>
> Section 4: Working with passwords
>
> Section 5: Securing the Boot Process and Hardware Resources

12. Chapter 12: Network Operations

> Section 1: Introduction to Networking
>
> Section 2: Browsers
>
> Section 3: Transferring Files

13. Chapter 13: Manipulating Text

> Section 1: cat and echo
>
> Section 2: sed and awk
>
> Section 3: File Manipulation Utilities
>
> Section 4: grep
>
> Section 5: Miscellaneous Text Utilities
>
> Section 6: Dealing with Large Files and Text-related Utilities

14. Chapter 14: Printing

> Section 1: Configuration
>
> Section 2: Printing Operations
>
> Section 3: Manipulating Postscript and PDF Files

15. Chapter 15: Bash Shell Scripting

> Section 1: Features and Capabilities
>
> Section 2: Syntax
>
> Section 3: Constructs

16. Chapter 16: Advanced Bash Scripting

> Section 1: String Manipulation
>
> Section 2: Boolean Expressions
>
> Section 3: The Case Statement
>
> Section 4: Looping Constructs
>
> Section 5: Script Debugging
>
> Section 6: Some Additional Useful Techniques

17. Chapter 17: Processes

> Section 1: Introduction to Processes and Process Attributes
>
> Section 2: Listing Processes
>
> Section 3: Process Metrics and Process Control
>
> Section 4: Starting Processes in the Future

18. Chapter 18: Common Applications

> Section 1: Internet Applications
>
> Section 2: Productivity and Development Applications
>
> Section 3: Multimedia Applications
>
> Section 4: Graphics Editors and Utilities

Comment: Sounds good. But can this be considered quite enough to say I have a good knowledge on linux

Comment: When you put a question this way, it seems to be too opinion-based. I can say that knowing this topics will give you good foundation and confidence in using OS. Depending on how deep you learn all this your knowledge may eventually become more than good.